# C++ std::queue does not want to push()

Tags: c++

This is a simple class and simple test function:

```
#include <queue>
#include <string>

namespace {
    using namespace std;
}

class NameStream {
    queue<string> stream;

public:
    string operator * () { return stream.front(); }
    NameStream &operator ++(int) { stream.pop(); return *this; }
    NameStream &operator ++() { stream.pop(); return *this; }
    NameStream &operator <<(string name) { stream.push(name); }

    operator bool() { return !stream.empty(); }
};

inline void nameStreamTest() {
    NameStream &stream = *new NameStream;

    stream << "hi" << "hey" << "hoy";

    while (stream) {
        printf("%s\n", (*stream++).c_str());
    }
}
```

It falls in

```
NameStream &operator <<(string name) { stream.push(name); }
```

inside queue's push procedure, here is the stack beyond my code:

```
#0  0x000b5079 in std::deque<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::push_back at stl_deque.h:1055
#1  0x000b50f2 in std::queue<std::string, std::deque<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > >::push at stl_queue.h:204
#2  0x000b511c in NameStream::operator<< at NameStream.h:24
#3  0x000b520f in nameStreamTest at NameStream.h:32
```

My experience fails in this case. What am I doing wrong?

P.S.:

```
NameStream &stream = *new NameStream;
```

Is used to clear off location of

```
stream
```

object at address (offset?) 0x7d (!) which causes same exception.

Comment: You are having `return *this;` in `operator <<` right?

Comment: Yes. It returns reference to self.

Comment: As an additional advice: using -Werror (or "treat warnings as errors") helps **a lot** with this kind of mistakes.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this: `NameStream &stream = *new NameStream;`? While that is valid C++, it is fairly uncommon, and in your particular case you seem to be leaking the `NameStream` resource (no `delete` is ever called). If you can, use local variables: `NameStream stream;`, and if you need to use dynamic allocation, avoid hiding it with a reference, and if possible encapsulate the resource in a smart pointer to handle the lifetime.

Answer (score 6):

Put a return statement at the end of your function.

```
NameStream &operator <<(string name) { stream.push(name); return *this; }
```

**Add**: Not returning a valid reference/value (when needed) will cause a UB and that will cause hidden crashes or bad behavior which are often hard to debug (as in your case). So never ignore a compiler warning if it generates any.

Comment: @vitaut, I know that code doesn't give compile error. As @Heandel suggests, missing `return` will cause a runtime crash or bad behavior. I was pointing out the same

Comment: @vitaut Will it?  One obvious possible reason for the crash is that `operator<<` is called with an invalid pointer.  Which was "returned" from the previous `operator<<`.

Comment: Sorry, guys. Forget what I've said. This exactly answers what the OP is asking for. I think overconsumption of Guinness finally got me causing partial brain damage.

Answer (score 2):

It is failing as  postfix operator `++` is having higher precedence than operator `*`, so when for the last iteration of the loop is executed, you first `pop` from the queue and then try to do `front` by which time queue is empty. To solve this, the simplest way is to break it into two statements like:

```
while (stream) {
        printf("%s\n", (*stream).c_str());
        stream++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It falls in

```
NameStream &operator <<(string name) { stream.push(name); }
```

You don't return `*this`... by chaining the `operator<<()` calls, the second and third one have no valid object address to work on.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a number of problems in the code.

1. Missing return in `operator<<` (as pointed out by iammilind and others) which causes the runtime error that you observe. It can be corrected as follows:

   ```
   NameStream &operator <<(string name) { stream.push(name); return *this; }
   ```
2. Another problems is due to the sequence of calls in the body of your while loop which is:

   1. operator ++(int)
   2. operator * ()

   Therefore in the last iteration you first `pop()` in `operator++(int)` and then try to call `front()` in `operator*()` on an empty queue which will cause a runtime error.

   The easiest way to fix it is to rewrite your while loop as follows.

   ```
   while (stream) {
     printf("%s\n", (*stream).c_str());
     ++stream;
   }
   ```
3. Memory leak. You call allocate a NameStream object using `new`, but never call `delete`. An easy solution is to allocate your stream object on stack:

   ```
   NameStream stream;
   ```

Comment: That's obviously a problem as well (he doesn't provide the correct semantics for postfix `++`).  But his code doesn't get that far; the stack walkback shows it failing in `operator<<` (doubtlessly because of the missing return).  (At a higher level, this is a perfect example of operator overloading abuse.  Pairing `<<` with `++`.)

Comment: @James Kanze: The OP's code may or may not go this far depending on the compiler. In my test (compiled with g++ in debug mode) it did pass operator<< fine. However missing return is indeed the problem.

Comment: The OP's code didn't get that far.  He posted a stack trace showing a crash in `operator<<`.  Whether it actually does depends on how the compiler generates code; if the `ostream` reference happens to be in the register used for return values at the end of `operator<<`, the code might work.  Apparently, this wasn't the case with his compiler.  (An interesting idea for a debugging mode: when falling off the end, put `0xdeadbeaf` in the register used for return values.)